# keras MLP accuracy zero

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

The following is my MLP model,

```
layers = [10,20,30,40,50]
model = keras.models.Sequential()
#Stacking Layers
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layers[0], input_dim = input_dim, activation='relu'))
#Defining the shape of input
for layer in layers[1:]:
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layer, activation='relu'))
    #Layer activation function
# Output layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
#Pre-training
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
#Training
model.fit(train_set, test_set, validation_split = 0.10, epochs = 50, batch_size = 10, shuffle = True, verbose = 2)
# evaluate the network
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(train_set, test_set)
print("\nLoss: %.2f, Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (loss, accuracy*100))
#predictions
predt = model.predict(final_test)
print(predt)
```

The problem is that, accuracy is always 0, error log as shown,

```
Epoch 48/50 - 0s - loss: 1.0578 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.4885 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 
Epoch 49/50 - 0s - loss: 1.0578 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.4885 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 
Epoch 50/50 - 0s - loss: 1.0578 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.4885 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 
2422/2422 [==============================] - 0s 17us/step
```

> Loss: 1.00, Accuracy: 0.00%

As suggested i've changed my learning signal from -1,1 to 0,1 and yet, the following is the error log

```
Epoch 48/50 - 0s - loss: 8.5879 - acc: 0.4672 - val_loss: 8.2912 - val_acc: 0.4856 
Epoch 49/50 - 0s - loss: 8.5879 - acc: 0.4672 - val_loss: 8.2912 - val_acc: 0.4856 
Epoch 50/50 - 0s - loss: 8.5879 - acc: 0.4672 - val_loss: 8.2912 - val_acc: 0.4856 
2422/2422 [==============================] - 0s 19us/step
```

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: It has Open, High, Low, Close stock data and output learning signal as  -1 and +1

Comment: I think the target values should be 0/1 not -1/+1.

Comment: I've tried that, posted another error log.

Comment: Try changing your optimzer to another e.g adadelta the different parameter they pass like learning rate may help your model converge faster.

Answer (score 0):

You code is very hard to read. This is not the recommended standard to write Keras model. Try this and let us know what you get. Assuming X is a matrix where the rows are the instances and the columns are the features. And Y is the labels

You need to add a channel as the last dimension as explained when using the TensorFlow backend. Furthermore the labels should be split into 2 nodes for better chance of success. A single neuron mapping is often less successful, than using a probabilistic output with 2 nodes.

```
n = 1000         # Number of instances
m = 4            # Number of features
num_classes = 2  # Number of output classes

... # Your code for loading the data

X = X.reshape(n, m,) 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

Build your model. The last layer should use either sigmoid or softmax for a classification task. Try to use the Adadelta optimizer it has been shown to produce better results by traversing the gradient more efficiently, and reducing oscillations. We will also use cross entropy as our loss function as is standard with classification tasks. Binary cross entropy is fine too.

Try to use a standard model configuration. An increasing number of nodes does not really make much sense. The model should look like a prism, small set of input features, many hidden nodes, and a small set of output nodes. You should aim for the least number of hidden layers, make the layers fatter, rather than adding layers.

```
input_shape = (m,)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

You can get a summary of your model using

```
model.summary()
```

Train your model

```
epochs = 100
batch_size = 128
# Fit the model weights.
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

To view what happened during training

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,10))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)

# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='lower right')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```